# Read request.POST with json data (Django)

Tags: python, json, django, request

I'm new on "Django".

I want read json data in "django" view. These data send from http://www.payplug.fr to my website into `request.post`. Here are my `urls.py` :

```
from credits.views import retour_ipn

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
    ('^c/retour_ipn/$', retour_ipn),
)
```

And `credits.views` :

```
@csrf_exempt
def retour_ipn(request):

    from base64 import b64decode, b64encode

    header = request.META['HTTP_PAYPLUG_SIGNATURE']
    signature = b64decode(header)
    body = request.raw_post_data
    data = json.loads(body)
    print data
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

After, signature will be analyses for save data in "django" models.

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: hi,
I don't read the "data" dict and don't read request.HEADER.
I can give you php function if you want.

Comment: What django version are you using?